# How do I protect API keys used to authorize an iframe-based client?

Tags: web-application, api, iframe

I'm building a service composed of a backend API and an embed-able, iframe-based, front-end client. Only authorized customers should be able to access the backend API via the iframe embed. My plan is to give paying customer's an API key.

Based on [another asker's question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61652/how-should-i-validate-an-api-key-for-a-web-service-deployed-via-iframe), my understanding is that services typically embed the API key in the iframe resource, as follows:

```
<iframe src='http://service.com/API_KEY_GOES_HERE/' height='750' width='640'>
```

The backend then authorizes the request based on the API key and the referrer (which can be spoofed from my understanding).

**My question:**
Typically, you try to keep API keys secret. How does this keep the API key safe? It would seem that anyone would be able to grab the key by inspecting my customer's page source where the iframe is embedded?

Comment: Please try changing your title to an actual question. However, I think the approach you've described is fundamentally flawed. In general you cannot properly secure your secret (API key in this case) if it's sent to the client anyhow. In this use case the secret should probably stay serverside only and a whole other mechanism needs to be introduced for whatever is to be achieved with this.